# Origen de términos en pinturas de castas

Tags: etimología, hispanoamérica, español-medio

El mestizaje hace parte casi implícita del mundo latinoamericano desde su nacimiento. En particular quiero hacer enfoque en las [pinturas de castas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pintura_de_castas), donde se empieza a establecer las distinciones según los ancestros del sujeto en cuestión. En particular, me llaman la atención algunos de los términos cuya etimología no se hace presente en el DLE: (dejo las palabras con el significado, para quien le pueda interesar)

- **Barcino**:  En la América colonial, nacido de padres de distintas razas, especialmente de albarazado y mulata, o de mulato y albarazada
- **Calpamulo**:  En la América colonial, nacido de padres de distintas razas, especialmente de albarazado y negra, o de negro y albarazada.
- **Jíbaro**: En la América colonial, nacido de padres de distintas razas, especialmente de albarazado y calpamula, o de calpamulo y albarazada

Cabe aclarar que en el mapa de diccionarios, hacia 1925 las palabras se dan por válidas en México y que las pinturas de castas son un producto cultural de la Nueva España. Ese mismo mestizaje en otros territorios de hispanoamérica se trataban con otras palabras, pero eso ya es tema de otra pregunta

Comment: Las tres palavras se encuentran todas en: https://dle.rae.es/jíbaro

Answer (score 3):

Según parece, las pinturas de castas son una mina de oro para los etimólogos. No hay mucha claridad con respecto al origen de esas decenas de palabras, muchas de las cuales se aplicaron primero a razas de animales y después a los humanos, en una especie de "pigmentocracia".

Las siguientes son solo posibilidades acerca de las palabras que mencionas:

- **barcino** y **albarazado**, derivan del árabe *al baraz*, "una tonalidad de negro rojizo manchado", y éste a su vez del arábigo *baraxa* que significa "manchado", refiriéndose a la piel de los caballos y, por comparación, a la lepra y los leprosos.
- **calpamulo** (al igual que la palabra española **mulato**) viene de *mula*, ese animal que es cruce de yegua y asno. *Mula* viene del latín *mulus* que significa "macho". El inicio *calpa-* es incierto, pero se sugiere que corresponde al nahuatl *calpan*, que significa "donde están las casas", dado que a veces se dice *calpan mulato*. (*Calpan* también está en el nombre *Tegucigalpa*, la capital de Honduras). En otras partes dicen (sin explicar) que *calpan mulato* es "peor que mulato".
- **jíbaro** sería una metátesis (cambio en el orden de los sonidos) de *guajiro*, que es la palabra arahuaca con que algunas tribus antillanas se denominaban a sí mismas. Aunque otros dicen que es exactamente lo contrario: *guajiro* sería una metátesis de *jibaro*, proveniente del taíno *jiba* ("piedra"): "los que trabajan con las piedras".

Comment: Si viene de la RAE, hay que indicarlo.